# CSS/HTML background image fixed issue

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

```css
    CSS
    
    .as {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      border: 5px solid red;
      position: absolute;
      left: 25%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      
    }
    .ab {
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border: 2px solid green;
      background-color: green;
    }
    .cd {
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border: 2px solid blue;
      background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
 
    HTML
    $div class="as"$
            $div class="ab"$123$/div$
            $div class="cd"$123$/div$
    $/div$
```

When I run it, I have green and blue boxes in a big red box. The green and blue are on the left corner.
since the parent container, which is "as" has display: flex and flex-direction: column
I can't go to the left bottom corner.
Is there a way to go to the left bottom? besides make it position: relative and bottom: %.
Thank you
Hi, I am practicing CSS

Comment: Please post the 'rendered' HTML or a [mcve] for easier/faster troubleshooting

Comment: use the code snippet tool provided by this forum

Answer (score 0):

Do you need use property the justify-content with value flex-end to the left bottom corner

Look this example bellow

```css
.as {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.bottom-left {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.bottom-right {
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.ab {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-color: green;
}
.cd {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Bottom left</p>
<div class="as bottom-left">
  <div class="ab">123</div>
  <div class="cd">123</div>
</div>
<p>Bottom right</p>
<div class="as bottom-right">
  <div class="ab">123</div>
  <div class="cd">123</div>
</div>
```